# YASnippet: How to resume (or reactivate) snippets after exiting them

Tags: yasnippet

After exiting [`yasnippet`](https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet) snippets that contain one or more [tab stops](https://capitaomorte.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html#sec-3-3), I often find myself wanting to go back and modify content that I entered at the tab stops. Of course, I can do this using standard movement and editing commands, but it would be much easier if I could simply *reactivate*, say, the last snippet I inserted and <kbd>TAB</kbd> through the fields again.

Another frequent use case is exiting snippets prematurely. I sometimes do this on purpose, but more often than not this happens because I accidentally hit <kbd>C-g</kbd> (or some other command that cancels the snippet).

**Q:** Is there a way to resume or reactivate a snippet after exiting it?

I ran <kbd>M-x</kbd> `apropos` for various combinations of `yas`/`yasnippet` and `resume`/`reactivate`, but that didn't turn up anything useful.

---

**UPDATE**

As @Stefan helpfully points out in the comments, it is possible to call `undo` to reactivate a snippet. However, this is only useful as long as the current buffer stays unmodified: If I exit a snippet, make some unrelated modifications in other parts of the buffer, and then hit <kbd>C-/</kbd> (`undo`), Emacs first reverts the most recent changes instead of resuming the snippet, which (in most cases) is not what I want.

Comment: Have you tried to just `undo`?

Comment: @Stefan I tried it just now, thanks! It addresses some of my use cases, but unfortunately not all of them (see recent updates to my question).

Comment: We can wait and see. But I think `undo` is the best you're gonna get.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment, you can `undo` to reactive a snippet.  And if you want to reactivate a yasnippet without first undoing your subsequent changes, you can use `undo-in-region`, i.e. select a region of text that contains the snippet and do `undo`.

Comment: Thanks for upgrading your comment to an answer. Unfortunately, using `undo-in-region` to reactivate a snippet doesn't work for me. If I (1) expand a snippet, (2) cancel it, (3) insert some text in another part of the buffer, (4) select text containing the snippet, (5) hit `C-/`, I get "No further undo information for region". Assuming you tested this, could you add a working example to your answer?

Comment: Hmm... no, I didn't actually test it, I looked at the code instead and it has what is needed for it to work, AFAICT.  You should probably report it as a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shift tab to go backward.